# Install a GUI (KDE) on a centos 5.3

Tags: centos, vnc, kde

I'm trying to install KDE on a vps of centos 5.3. These are the steps:

```
yum install kdepim
yum install vnc vnc-server x11-xorg

vncserver
vncserver -kill :1
vim ~/.vnc/xstartup
#(replaced the last line with: "startkde &")

rm -rf /tmp/.X1*
vncserver
```

When I try to connect using a remote client of UltraVNC, I'm being prompted to supply a password - but after that it's stuck.

While executing 'ps' I can see:

```
artsmessage -i Sound server informational message:??Error while initializing the sound driver:?SNDCTL_DSP_SETFMT f
```

Any idea what/how?

Answer (score 2):

yum groupinstall "Group Name"   command should solve the problem.
For instance , in case you want to install GNOME desktop environment ou would type :
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"
and if you want KDE command would read:
yum groupinstall  "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"

But how you'd know what exact group names are and what application software groups are
available for install ?
There is yum grouplist  command which will tell you what's available for you to choose from.

You can try (CHOOSE ANY ONE)

**yum groupinstall gnome**

**yum groupinstall kde**

Here's a good tutorial for you with more detail and in depth discussion :
http://www.montanalinux.org/centos5-debian-style.html

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

- First, install KDE group using `yum groupinstall KDE`. Check if the
  name is different in the group list with  `yum grouplist`.
- Make sure you update `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` with KDE

  `DESKTOP="KDE"`
   `DISPLAYMANAGER="KDE"`
- Make sure you start the server(s) from `/etc/init.d/vncserver`
- Run `vncpasswd` at shell and set the vncpasswd.
- Replace `startx &` in the last line in  `~/.vnc/xstartup` file with `startkde &`
- Install `switchdesk` tool as well

  `# yum install switchdesk`
- run `yum install system-switch-displaymanager` and run `system-switch-displaymanager` and change the display manager.
- Run `switchdesk` to shift to KDE from GNOME in all your X-related files
  `switchdesk kde`
- If still does not go well, try checking with your sound card. See if
  a reboot works or reconfiguring/removing the sound device drivers.